# Как сделать моментальный бинарный поиск в txt файле?

Tags: python, поиск, бинарный-поиск

Есть файл с миллионами отсортированных строк file.txt (1,2 ГБ) вот пример

```
NrdL9TwD3P2ePvUNzjuzEkHgMF
VtaQZoDxaYKWg6zN2eyysPgWxyzpeuS
VtqndxgoBoSgabMS2Hi8vikLuwBsGov
yNNXkWxa3ACnJnE29Z9qzUnM6eA
ZWZ8yutjQ7xnRMwXKKQviMxSU
VvEY1uxWp3zGdPqv5L7Q1CQ1VzA8nfE
VvLjsvzcga5cfwqQZpXAxEDhVuQY5vP
VvRVzPfn7PuQgkFcmMYQHcnzKN7yVk
vkyZ1p6yuk6cWWDoSHMzm13FMyWUbD
wMCwXk2sYZ3NyJjMBhWzJwcxqHxiLm
wZVQiZMKPzHLcj72cF8dK1mtNMDpsd
Zt7hQJZQb7k43SvxDnYQrdpTiNLQh
VwZvfgXo9TAreDhexjauK7vu2D62DF8
JxAE8XZjE5b4bYuV9KZghka6eHN
```

И мне нужно моментально определить, есть ли например *wZVQiZMKPzHLcj72cF8dK1mtNMDpsd* в этом файле. Вот я нашел пример из интернета: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58140529/binary-search-in-large-txt-with-python-ordered-by-hash

```
FIELD_SIZE=40+1
def binarySearch(mm, l, r, x):
    while l <= r:
        mid = int(l + (r - l)/2);
        mid_slice = mm[mid*FIELD_SIZE:(mid+1)*FIELD_SIZE]
        mid_slice = mid_slice.decode('utf-8').strip()
        if mid_slice == x:
            return mid
        elif mid_slice < x:
            l = mid + 1
        else:
            r = mid - 1

    return -1

with open('file.txt', 'r+b') as f:
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
    size = f.tell()
    result = binarySearch(mm, 0, size/FIELD_SIZE, 'wZVQiZMKPzHLcj72cF8dK1mtNMDpsd')
    if result != -1:
        print("Element is present at index % d" % result)
    else:
        print("Element is not present in array")
```

Но он не работает на моем примере. Как его переделать, чтобы он искал наличие в моем файле?
Я также пробовал читать строки, но мой ПК намертво зависал.

Comment: А.... в чём тут выражается отсортированность строк? И одинакова ли их длина?

Comment: MBo, строки я взял рандомные, на самом деле они отсортированы. Размер строки бывает в редких случаях разный

Comment: Можно ли реорганизовывать файл? Что значит "моментально", сколько времени на это даётся?

Comment: Для строк разной длины придётся создавать индексный файл

Comment: Моментально, значит меньше чем за секунду.

Comment: Пример явно рассчитан на файл с фиксированной длиной поля. Раз строки разной длины, то вам встав на очередную точку в файле надо сначала найти ближайший перевод каретки, что бы определить начало строки. Начиная со следующего символа и до следующего перевода каретки - вот у вас целая строка, можно сравнивать ее на больше-меньше, что бы определить в какую сторону дальше двигаться. И главное что бы сортировка строк в файле позволяла сравнивать их правильно на больше-меньше, т.е. должна быть лексиграфической. ну и предусмотреть сплошной поиск в примерно найденном блоке размером скажем в 4кб

Comment: прикол в том, что эти строки отсортированы по алфавиту, и можно ориентироваться по минимальной строчке

Comment: Покажите короткий пример реальных данных

Comment: Было что-то тут уже  подобное

Answer (score 1):

Можно модифицировать алгоритм, чтоб он:

1. когда делил пополам и искал mid, то делал сдвиг до ближайшего начала строки
2. когда вырезал кусок mid_slice, то брал не фиксированный размер `FIELD_SIZE`, а опять же искал следующий конец строки.

Сейчас не работает потому, что при делении попадаете внутрь строки.

Вот так вот на примере из вопроса - работает. Нужно, конечно, тестировать на всякие пограничные случаи, я совсем этому не уделял внимания, для демонстрации идеи - думаю сгодится.

На 220MB файле со строками ~20 символов ищет за 100ms.

```
import mmap
import os
import sys


eol_bytes = list(enumerate(os.linesep.encode('utf-8')))

def is_eol(mm, i, size):
    # логика для определения конца строки
    return i + len(eol_bytes) <= size \
        and all(b == mm[i + n] for n, b in eol_bytes)


def binarySearch(mm, l, r, x, size):
    while l <= r:
        mid = int(l + (r - l)/2);
        prev_eol = mid
        while prev_eol >= 0 and not is_eol(mm, prev_eol, size):
            prev_eol -= 1
        next_eol = mid + 1
        while next_eol < size and not is_eol(mm, next_eol, size):
            next_eol += 1
        mid_slice = mm[prev_eol+1:next_eol]
        mid_slice = mid_slice.decode('utf-8').strip()
        if mid_slice == x:
            return prev_eol + 1
        elif mid_slice < x:
            l = next_eol + 1
        else:
            r = prev_eol - 1
    return -1

filename = sys.argv[1]
search_string = sys.argv[2]

with open(filename, 'r+b') as f:
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
    size = f.tell()
    result = binarySearch(mm, 0, size, search_string, size)
    if result != -1:
        print("Element is present at index % d" % result)
    else:
        print("Element is not present in array")
```

Comment: Похоже, что неправильную позицию возвращает. Под Windows возвращает позицию за символ до начала искомой строки (кроме нулевой, там позиция правильная).

Comment: Ну да, не учитывается длина `eol_bytes` при возвращении в return. Windows под рукой нет. По идее `return prev_eol + len(eol_bytes)` должно помочь.

Comment: В общем, поправил немного вашу процедуру. Добавил как ответ.

Answer (score 0):

По мотивам ответа @RomanKonoval ...

```
def binarySearch(mm, l, r, x, size):
    eol_bytes = os.linesep.encode()
    x = x.encode()
    while l <= r:
        mid = l + (r - l)//2
        prev_eol = mm.rfind(eol_bytes, 0, mid + len(eol_bytes))
        if prev_eol == -1: prev_eol = 0
        next_eol = mm.find(eol_bytes, mid + 1)
        if next_eol == -1: next_eol = size
        pos = prev_eol+len(eol_bytes) if eol_bytes == mm[prev_eol:prev_eol+len(eol_bytes)] else prev_eol
        mid_slice = mm[pos:next_eol]
        if mid_slice == x:
            return pos
        elif mid_slice < x:
            l = next_eol + len(eol_bytes)
        else:
            r = prev_eol
    return -1
```

Работает корректно с нативными окончаниями строк под любой ОС.
Также раза в 3-4 быстрее оригинала. Хотя это не существенно, ибо у меня поиск занимал около полторы тысячных секунды на файле 2ГБ с 46.6 миллионами случайных строк длиной 40-50 символов каждая.

```
Orig:  1.51013 ms
New :  0.39095 ms
```