# Как увеличить скорость работы программы, при переборе?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно написать программу для взлома шифра Виженера. Собственного говоря, я её написал, но столкнулся с проблемой, которая связана со поиска ключа. Получив возможный размер ключа, я основываясь на частоте символов в тексте предполагаю, из каких букв может состоять это слово. А чтобы вручную не перебирать все возможные варианты слова, я пытаюсь найти данное слово в словаре. Для сокращения времени поиска слова в словаре использую программу grep, так как мой поиск будет куда хуже. Но несмотря ни на что, программа ищет слово крайне долго. Допусти слово "кот" она искала минут 15.

```
from collections import Counter
import itertools
import subprocess
import sys

ru_alphabet = ('а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф',
               'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я', '_')


def test_kasiski(text: str) -> list: # тут получаю длинну слова
    size_select_block = 3
    counter_size = []
    select_str_block = []
    for index_start_letter in range(len(text) - size_select_block):
        select_str = text[index_start_letter: index_start_letter + size_select_block]
        if select_str in select_str_block:
            continue
        select_str_block.append(select_str)
        index_start = index_start_letter
        index_end = index_start_letter
        counter = 0
        for index_letter in range(index_start_letter + size_select_block, len(text) - size_select_block):
            if select_str == text[index_letter: index_letter + size_select_block]:
                index_end = index_letter
                counter += 1

        if index_start == index_end:
            continue
        else:
            counter_size.append((index_end - index_start, counter, select_str_block[-1]))

    counter_size = sorted(counter_size, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    counter_size = [item for item in counter_size if item[1] != 0]

    return counter_size


def split_text_parts(text: str, size_key: int) -> list: # использую для записи букв в блоки
    part = [[] for _ in range(size_key)]
    for index_letter in range(0, len(text), size_key):
        for index in range(size_key):
            part[index].append(text[index_letter + index:index_letter + index + 1])
    return part


def gen_code(text, lang) -> list: # получаю список индексов букв из словаря
    num_key = []
    for letter in list(text):
        num_key.append(lang.index(letter))
    return num_key


def devi(text, key, lang=ru_alphabet) -> str:
    code_key = gen_code(key, lang)
    text_key = gen_code(text, lang)

    code_text_key = []
    index_letter = 0
    mod = len(lang)
    while index_letter < len(text_key):
        for iter in range(len(code_key)):
            index_code_letter = (text_key[index_letter] - code_key[iter]) % mod
            code_text_key.append(lang[index_code_letter])
            index_letter += 1
            if index_letter >= len(text_key):
                break
    str_text = "".join(code_text_key)
    return str_text


def get_text(text: str, block: list):
    for select_key in range(len(block[0])):
        key = [elem[select_key][0] for elem in block]
        key = "".join(key)
        text = text.replace("\n", "")
        print(devi(text, key))
        select = input("\n>")
        if select == '1':
            return "OK"


# [[('г', 25), ('д', 11), ('й', 10)], [('н', 26), ('ь', 15), ('ъ', 8)], [('я', 16), ('р', 15), ('щ', 11)], [('й', 22), ('п', 12), ('к', 11)], [('_', 17), ('е', 10), ('в', 8)]]
def all_combinations(list_combinations, size_key):
    all_combinations = ""
    for elem in list_combinations:
        all_combinations = all_combinations + "".join([l[0] for l in elem])

    list_comb = list(itertools.combinations(all_combinations, size_key))
    str_comb = ["".join(elem) for elem in list_comb]
    return str_comb


def h_vi(text: str, list_counter_size: list):
    for counter_size in list_counter_size:
        for size_key in range(1, counter_size[0]):
            if counter_size[0] % size_key != 0:
                continue

            size_key = 3 # можно удалить(использую, чтобы поиск начинался сразу с нужной длинны)

            text_parts = split_text_parts(text, size_key) # делю текст на части
            block = []
            for part in text_parts:
                count_part = Counter(part)
                block.append(count_part.most_common(10)) # беру 10 самых часто встечаемых буквы в блоке

            text = text.replace("\n", "")
            # тут наинается перебор
            all_combinators = all_combinations(block, size_key) # все возможные комбинации букв
            if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
                for str_ in all_combinators:
                    find_word = subprocess.run(['grep', "-w", f'{str_}', 'russian.txt'],
                                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True).stdout.split('\n') # перебираю все возможные комбинации и ищу совпадения в словаре
                    if len(find_word) == 1: # если ничег не нашо, то беру следующую комбинацию
                        continue 
                    # тут заканчивается
                    if str_ in find_word: # если есть совпадение, то декодиру, если ответ не == 1 продолжаю
                        print("#\n", str_)
                        print(devi(text, str_))
                        select = input(">")
                        if select == '1':
                            return "OK"
            else:  # тут происходит чистый перебор(но на него безразницы)
                for i in range(len(all_combinators)):
                    if size_key == 1:
                        for elem in all_combinators:
                            if elem == " " or elem == "_":
                                continue
                            print(devi(text, elem))
                            select = input("\n>")
                            if select == '1':
                                return "OK"
                        break
                    with open("russian.txt", "r") as word:
                        while True:
                            select_word = word.readline().replace("\n", "")
                            if not select_word:
                                break
                            if all_combinators[i] == select_word:
                                c = all_combinators[i]
                                g = 0
                                print(devi(text, c))
                                select = input("\n>")
                                if select == '1':
                                    return "OK"

    return None

# 'мой_дядя_самых_честных_правил_когда_не_в_шутку_занемог_он_уважать_себя_заставил_и_лучше_выдумать_не_мог_его_пример_другим_наука_но_боже_мой_какая_скука_с_больным_сидеть_и_день_и_ночь_не_отходя_ни_шагу_прочь_какое_низкое_коварство_полуживого_забавлять_ему_подушки_поправлять_печально_подносить_лекарство_вздыхать_и_думать_про_себя_когда_же_черт_возьмет_тебя_так_думал_молодой_повеса_летя_в_пыли_на_почтовых_всевышней_волею_зевеса_наследник_всех_своих_родных_друзья_людмилы_и_руслана_с_героем_моего_романа_без_предисловий_сей_же_час_позвольте_познакомить_вас_онегин_добрый_мой_приятель_родился_на_брегах_невы_где_может_быть_родились_вы'
# вгогждргумьчгыйзтгкйгетпйгыцтгвгртзчгйэйгходлдц_гцйуйф_гвглсдбгжгждьйнгжтпйгрйсвгуфйлфйс_йргсдодлдц_гстгжягогртйнгсйхыдхцстнгитпйгщтц_годупбгкдптхцмгщфдсвгжягсйгтхцджмцйгрйсвгхсдыдпдгвгртпыдц_гщтцйпдгутжйф_цйгртйзтгхцяидгжягсйгчлсдпмгегсмотзид

if __name__ == "__main__":
    text = "цьыйтромсыоюдвсаувьымянаъофтщсфьхоосчусмнйэ_ьэнщкычцьхйьяйафкфтьйсыууинщкягкръхнъйщдаечйрмоаюк_нйычйъ_ннчньсщюъцубйтбэсъцнякаькняшнушфчйъ_унькштинвфаькнвйп_хйядъсыццп_нйцсоуяенъйы_айсчусш_жштрйыъйетнасщю_айсфоьшусчцщфьчйш_мобы_фшнашщдрцфшс_йхтлофхмгенчцасщьцэеьтнашэбкрэи_нйэчаоэеы_йэ_оы_ыцгенэпштъягмьсмхцдвтьйстнцэътьйсщю_йячлмсфьхоосрусаубьнфшхнцугй_члмсьоьйтдцоэйъ_хьцшчсщьфпятйщчьмсмнадщъйытйэ_а__мижйрвпрмбычунфшщчзнщпрчыосчовхуцчцьйрвпвсыр_твсъьцчижйтбэхнинэзтютщмйцсъавхоякнвйсчъьчцнюшухшнбшътчослущйэбптъыщ_мцыйячуншпникясщьщмьэе_чйэ_сытфьют_нйртын_чухтысоьуъиыйъ_унаъцрьуэенбштъхярйытйпбпстяняпрмйсцпнюшфчьнуд_нйю_оцэтянйрмйцэтнухцвьоэтнюшчсацгк_чхйсьоюйычфьхооснаэищстнрйы_йрбптччнвпрчънцхмсцуяи"
# print(devi(text, 'кот')) # у text ключ - "кот"
    all = test_kasiski(text)  # тут не существенных проблем
    a = h_vi(text, all) # а вот тут проблемы со скоростью
    print(a)
```

Ума не приложy, как ускорить работу программы. Можете что-то посоветовать ?
Проблемная часть отмечена (тут начинается перебор) - (тут заканчивается)

Comment: ай многа букаф.

Comment: Не знаю, как по другому объяснить.

Comment: А словарь большой? Просто запуск процесса - это довольно время затратная операция. Да ещё и grep какое-то время по файлу каждый раз бегает.

Comment: Если файл словаря большой для полной загрузки в память, но там просто заранее отсортированные слова, то можно применить [быстрый бинарный поиск по файлу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1289511/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b2-txt-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5/1291887#1291887).

Comment: А нельзя ли хотя бы функции как-то понятно называть? `h_vi` - это вот что, например?

Comment: hacking - h; Виженер - vi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если предварительно загрузить файл со словами в память, то ищет мгновенно.

```
def h_vi(text: str, list_counter_size: list):
    with open("russian.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        words_rus = set(s.strip() for s in f.readlines())

    for counter_size in list_counter_size:
        for size_key in range(1, counter_size[0]):
            if counter_size[0] % size_key != 0:
                continue

            size_key = 3 # можно удалить(использую, чтобы поиск начинался сразу с нужной длинны)

            text_parts = split_text_parts(text, size_key) # делю текст на части
            block = []
            for part in text_parts:
                count_part = Counter(part)
                block.append(count_part.most_common(10)) # беру 10 самых часто встечаемых буквы в блоке

            text = text.replace("\n", "")
            # тут наинается перебор
            all_combinators = all_combinations(block, size_key) # все возможные комбинации букв

            for str_ in all_combinators:
                if str_ in words_rus: # если есть совпадение, то декодиру, если ответ не == 1 продолжаю
                    print("#\n", str_)
                    print(devi(text, str_))
                    select = input(">")
                    if select == '1':
                        return "OK"
```

Проверял под Windows, предварительно найдя [какой-то файлик](http://blog.harrix.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/word_rus.zip) с русскими существительными в 34_000 строк (штук).